# How would postgres treat a expression that exists in result column and "where" clause at same time?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions

I coded a function in Postgresql-11, in order to verify whether a column is correct.

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE trade_days
(
    trade_day date NOT NULL,
    previ_day date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trade_days_pkey PRIMARY KEY (trade_day)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prev_day(
    IN now_day_ DATE, OUT pd_ DATE )
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $func$
BEGIN
SELECT MAX( trade_day ) FROM trade_days WHERE trade_day < now_day_ INTO pd_;
END
$func$;
```

And then use it in a query:

```
select *, prev_day(trade_day) pd
from trade_days where previ_day <> prev_day(trade_day)
order by trade_day;
```

So I can find out those rows with incorrect "previ_day" column value.

Now I'm wondering how would postgres process the expression `prev_day(trade_day)`.

Would the expression be evaluted twice for every-row?

In other words, my function `prev_day()` will be executed twice for each row?

I tried another way like:

```
select *, prev_day(trade_day) pd
from trade_days where previ_day <> pd
order by trade_day;
```

But it can't pass compilation!

> ERROR:  column "pd" does not exist
>
> LINE 2: from trade_days where previ_day <> pd
>
> ```
>                                       ^
> ```
>
> SQL state: 42703 Character: 69

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer might be evident from the explain plan; have you looked at it? Perhaps a function is not the best way to do what you are trying to do; so, what is it that you're trying to do?